# How do I remove product duplicates in a view?

Tags: views, 8, commerce

In my view I have duplicate entities for my product list, this is different from Drupal 7 as you could use the distinct module.

How can I remove the duplicates from my commerce product views in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal Commerce has duplicate entities because a product is referenced from multiple variations, any field you add to a variation type will find multiple duplications in your view most notably in images but could be any field in example t-shirt size.

An easy way to remove these is to set in your view:

```
FILTER CRITERIA
Product: Variations:delta (= 0)
```

[image]